# Get command line arguments in Ktor Application module instead of Main?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I am trying to build up an application from Ktor which eventually should be executed via a fatjar.
A fatjar allows the use of arguments like the following one:

`java -jar myApp.jar XXXXX YYYYY`

I know how to get the `XXXXX` in the main module (by using simple `args[0]`) but I have troubles to get that values in the Application modules.

I would like to do something like that:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val port = System.getenv("PORT")?.toInt() ?: 8080
    val status = args[0]
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = port, module = (Application::mainModule())).start(wait = true)
}

fun Application.mainModule() {
    routing {
        get("/status") {
            call.respondText(
                <status variable from main function>,
                contentType = ContentType.Text.Html
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace the method reference for the `module` parameter with a normal lambda.
Within this lambda you invoke the module function with parameters you want:

```
fun Application.mainModule(args: Array<String>) {
    routing {
        get("/status") {
            //...
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        mainModule(args)
    }
    server.start(wait = true)
}
```

**Details**

The function `embeddedServer` has `module` as last parameter. The type of the parameter is a function of the type `Application` without any parameter and with `Unit` as return value:

```
fun embeddedServer(..., module: Application.() -> Unit) : TEngine
```

That is the reason you can provide `Application::mainModule` a as function reference. It exactly matches the type definitions of the parameter. But you could also provide a trailing lambda instead of this function reference:

```
val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) { 
    // this is Application
    routing {
        get("/status") {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Within this lambda `this` is of type `Application` exactly as in your function `Application.mainModule`. That means in this lambda you can easily invoke other functions of type `Application`. In my answer I created the `Application.mainModule` with `args` as parameter and invoke this function within the trailing lambda.

Comment: This works neatly !!! Thank you Rene. I am struggling now to understand how this actually is working... If you could give me some guidance on why a lambda is helping here, it would be awesome. But that's already great!

Comment: Is there any way to this while still keeping the functionality of `io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)`?

Comment: @daka please checkout my answer, it should help.

Answer (score 2):

To pass a new configuration parameter, you can prepend it with `-P:propName=`.

So that if you want to pass a property named `csv` with a value from a command line, you can do the following:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val csvFileName = "-P:csv=${args[0]}"
    EngineMain.main(arrayOf(csvFileName))
}
```

You can also pass the parameters without the need of modifying `args` by using `-P:csv=myfile.csv` as a command-line parameter.

Then, in your modules, you can access it via `environment.config.property("csv").getString()`.

```kotlin
fun Application.module() {
    val csvFileName = environment.config.property("csv").getString()
    println(csvFileName)
}
```

You can read more about configuring Ktor application in [the official Ktor documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/configurations.html#command-line).

Comment: thanks, you think you can answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66279393/812919