# Ktor - Access variable initilized by main function in Application.module function

Tags: kotlin, ktor

```
var foo : String? = null

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit {
    foo = "Hello World"
    io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)
}

@Suppress("unused") // Referenced in application.conf
@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    // foo is null here
}
```

How can I access `foo` in `Application.module` and why is this an issue to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access such variables in your modules since Ktor loads your application (and modules ofc) in a different classloader.

When you call `EngineMain.main()`, it goes through a long chain of calls, and one of the steps is to create a new classloader in `createApplication()` method [here](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/afbdc140b248fe546b664f4bacd291d7b38057a3/ktor-server/ktor-server-host-common/jvm/src/io/ktor/server/engine/ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt#L132). The implementation of `createClassLoader()` is [here](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/afbdc140b248fe546b664f4bacd291d7b38057a3/ktor-server/ktor-server-host-common/jvm/src/io/ktor/server/engine/ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt#L144).

Comment: So the only way is to pass command line arguments to `Application.module` with `-P` and perform all initialization there?

Comment: @daka Probably there are some more ways, but the only way I know is what you said, so yes, that's true. Btw, you can have multiple modules, you're not restricted with the only one.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arbitrary arguments in the following format: `-P:<argument>` where `<argument>` is the actual name for your argument. In the `Application.module` you can access them via `config` object:

```
fun Application.main() {
    println(environment.config.property("<argument>").getString())
}
```

Comment: thanks, but why is `foo` null in `Application.module`?