# How to access user defined environment variable in Ktor

Tags: config, environment, ktor

I am using ktor as a web server. Users call a Kotlin Clikt command to start the server, passing to it a variable that is needed later when the backend processes certain REST requests.

The clikt class then starts the server takes a single parameter and this parameter is passed when starting the embedded server.  That code is here:

```
class StartServer : CliktCommand(help = "Starts PHGv2 BrAPI Server") {

    private val myLogger = LogManager.getLogger(StartServer::class.java)
    val dbPath by option(help = "Full path to folder where TileDB datasets are stored.   ")
        .default("")
        .validate {
            require(it.isNotBlank()) {
                "--db-path must not be blank"
            }
        }

    override fun run() {
        setupDebugLogging()

        // Verify the uri is valid.  We only care about the hvcf dataset,
        // so check that one explicitly
        val hvcfExists = verifyURI(dbPath,"hvcf_dataset")
        if (!hvcfExists) {
            myLogger.error("hvcf_dataset does not exist in $dbPath.  Exiting.")
            return
        }

        // Create an Args list to pass to the server
        // This tells the endpoint code where the datasets are located.
        val dbUri = "-P:TILEDB_URI=${dbPath}"
        val args = arrayOf(dbUri)

        // commandLineEnvironment reads the application.config file
        // https://ktor.io/docs/configuration.html#hocon-file
        embeddedServer(Netty, commandLineEnvironment(args)).start(wait = true)
    }
}
```

Later, when servicing a query that needs this configuration variable, I have this code:

```
private val config = HoconApplicationConfig(ConfigFactory.load())

//val tiledbURI = environment.config.property("TILEDB_URI").getString()
val tiledbURI = config.property("TILEDB_URI").getString()

object SamplesService {

    private val myLogger = LogManager.getLogger(SamplesService::class.java)

    // Cached map of all taxa. Key is genoid mapped to Sample object
    private val taxa: Map<String, Sample> by lazy {
        taxaMap("${tiledbURI}/hvcf_dataset")
    }
     ....
```

The value for tiledbURI is always null (but the code compiles).
If I follow the examples from the the documentation, it shows grabbing the values from environment:

```
val tiledbURI = environment.config.property("TILEDB_URI").getString()
```

But "environment" is not known and will not compile.  Is there a different import that is needed?  My related imports are:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import io.ktor.server.config.*
```

Am I missing an import?  Or does this variable only exist to start the server, and they are not stored in the config file for access further down?

UPDATE/EDIT:

The hcon config file is this:

```
callsPageSize=10
variantsPageSize=100

# For connecting to tiledb from ktor.  Users should un-comment
# and edit the TILEDB_URI variable to point to their tiledb folder
# When running junit tests,  replace ""/Users/lcj34" in the example below
# with the  path to your home directory.  The path should end with a /
# For other use cases, replace the path with the path to the tiledb folder
#TILEDB_URI="/Users/lcj34/temp/phgv2Tests/tempDir/testTileDBURI/"

# Server metadata params  You will need to fill these out to match your setup
contactEmail = "someone@cornell.edu"
documentationURL = "https://github.com/maize-genetics/phg_v2"
location = "Ithaca NY"
organizationName = "Institute for Genetic Diversity at Cornell University"
organizationURL = "https://www.maizegenetics.net/"
serverDescription = "Server to connect to the Maize PHG Tiledb through BrAPI calls."
serverName = "Maize  PHGv2"

ktor {
    deployment {
        port = 8080
        watch = [  build ]
    }
    application {
        modules = [ net.maizegenetics.phgv2.brapi.ApplicationKt.module ]
    }
}
```

Note on the commented out TILEDB_URI variable. Users that run our application do not have easy access to the config file as it is bundled in a fat jar.  The comment related to updating the TILEDB_URI variable in the config file is mostly for developer junit testing.

What we need is for the user to be able to pass us a value that we can set for this parameter.

Comment: Can you share your HOCON configuration file?

Comment: I added the HOCON config file to the original question.  I have tried following the suggestions at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245921/get-command-line-arguments-in-ktor-application-module-instead-of-main without success.

Comment: You need to explicitly specify the name of the environment variable as the HOCON property value, like `TILEDB_URI = ${TILEDB_URI}`. For more information see https://ktor.io/docs/configuration-file.html#environment-variables

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Still no joy.  If I un-comment the line in the application.conf file that begins with #TILEDB_URI=...  then add the line "TILEDB_URI=${TILEDB_URI}" to the ktor deployment clause it will work.  That is how we initially had this when we used the application.conf file to define this variable.  But when it is user defined and passed to the kotlin clikt class that starts the server, I get an error when the config file is read saying "com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$UnresolvedSubstitution ... Could not resolve substitution to a value: ${TILEDB_URI}".

Comment: You may find this HOCON documentation about substitution rules helpful (https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#substitutions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by making the following changes.  Basically, I pass the user parameter through to the ktor routing code.  The files shown above are changed as follows:

```
class StartServer : CliktCommand(help = "Starts PHGv2 BrAPI Server") {

    private val myLogger = LogManager.getLogger(StartServer::class.java)
    val dbPath by option(help = "Full path to folder where TileDB datasets are stored.   ")
        .default("")
        .validate {
            require(it.isNotBlank()) {
                "--db-path must not be blank"
            }
        }

    override fun run() {
        setupDebugLogging()

        // Verify the uri is valid.  We only care about the hvcf dataset,
        // so check that one explicitly
        val hvcfExists = verifyURI(dbPath,"hvcf_dataset")
        if (!hvcfExists) {
            myLogger.error("hvcf_dataset does not exist in $dbPath.  Exiting.")
            return
        }

        // Create an Args list to pass to the server
        // This tells the endpoint code where the datasets are located.
        val dbUri = "-P:TILEDB_URI=${dbPath}"
        //val dbUri = "TILEDB_URI=${dbPath}"
        val args = arrayOf(dbUri)

        val server = embeddedServer(Netty,port=8080) {
            module(args)
        }
        server.start(true)

    }

}
```

this is then processed in Application.kt via:

```
fun Application.module(args:Array<String>) {

    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(CallLogging)

    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(Json {
            prettyPrint = false
            isLenient = true
            encodeDefaults = true
        })
    }


    // Setup routing.  Individual endpoints create Kotlin Route extensions
    // to handle processing REST requests.

    routing {
        // this method routes brapi/v2/
        // Within apiRoute(), specific endpoint calls are handled
        apiRoute(args)
    }

}
```

We continue to pass this argument until it reaches the function that actually processes the data:

```
fun Route.samples(args:Array<String>) {

    val samplesService = SamplesService
    val tiledbURI = args[0].substringAfter("TILEDB_URI=").substringBefore(" ")

    route("/samples") {

        get("") {
            call.respond(
                SampleListResponse(
                    Metadata(),
                    SampleListResponseResult(samplesService.lcjAllTaxaNames(tiledbURI).toTypedArray())
                    
                )
            )
        }

    }
}
```

If there is a better way to pass the argument value, please let me know, but this works for now.